# How to choose date without a year in Cordova (or javascript in General)

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a task which I need to choose two dates without choosing the year, because choosing the year will be in later stages and for both,

Is there a way to make android and iOS only show us a day-month date picker from within Cordova?

Comment: no, but a 12-option <select> is not un-usable